# How to completely remove specific input fields in User Defined Java Class in Pentaho

Tags: java, pentaho-data-integration

I don't understand how to completely remove specific input fields when using the **User Defined Java Class** in **Pentaho Data Integration**.

Let's assume that I have input fields **A**, **B** and **C**. let's Say I want to concatenate the values in **B** and **C** (separated by a space), write the result in **C**, and leave only the fields with the names **A** and **C** without the field with the name **B** (the real problem is much more complicated).  I understand how to write the result in field **C**, but I don't know how to completely delete field **B**.

```
private String outFieldName1;
private String outFieldName2;
private String removeFieldName;

private int outFieldIndex1;
private int outFieldIndex2;
private int removeFieldIndex;

private Object[] inputRow;

private int inputRowMetaSize;
private int outputRowMetaSize;

public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{
    inputRow = getRow();
    if (inputRow == null) {
        setOutputDone();
        return false;
    }

    if (first) processMetadata();

    pushOutputRow( get(Fields.In, removeFieldName).getString(inputRow) + " "
                 + get(Fields.In, outFieldName2).getString(inputRow));

    return true;
}

private void processMetadata() throws KettleException {
    outFieldName1 = getParameter("OUT1");
    outFieldName2 = getParameter("OUT2");
    removeFieldName = getParameter("REMOVE");

    outFieldIndex1 = getInputRowMeta().indexOfValue(outFieldName1);
    outFieldIndex2 = getInputRowMeta().indexOfValue(outFieldName2);
    removeFieldIndex = getInputRowMeta().indexOfValue(removeFieldName);

    inputRowMetaSize = data.inputRowMeta.size();
    outputRowMetaSize = data.outputRowMeta.size();

    first=false;
}


private void pushOutputRow(String content) throws KettleException {
    Object[] outRow = RowDataUtil.allocateRowData(outputRowMetaSize);

    for (int fieldN=0; fieldN < inputRow.length; ++fieldN) {
        if(fieldN == outFieldIndex1) {
            outRow[fieldN] = inputRow[fieldN];
        } else if(fieldN == outFieldIndex2) {
            outRow[fieldN] = content;
        } else if(fieldN == removeFieldIndex) {
            outRow[fieldN] = "";
            // Unable to delete this row!
        }

    }

    putRow( data.outputRowMeta, outRow );
}
```

Comment: First off, one simple comment, between the step categories Transform and Utility, there's at least 30 different steps, in PDI, your last resort is the 'Modified Java Script Value'. From that, sounds like you could a use combination of Concat Fields and Select Values steps. You also don't HAVE to delete a column, you can just omit said column in your output, because depending on your workload, deleting a column can be very taxing on the transformation, much more than just omiting it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I gave a simple example where you can check what I want. This is my first question here. If necessary, I can copy somewhere the same simple example of the transformation from which I took the java code.

Comment: My real task is more complicated than this, and using the UDJC step saves me more than 10 steps and reduces the amount of data processed, the number of places where you need to change the set of fields, if necessary. For my task, UDJC works faster and with less memory consumption than a transformation written without IT on large amounts of data.

Comment: After my UDJC step, I am have to use Select Step and delete unnecessary columns. As far as I understand, Select Step is also written in Java and somehow does it. I don't understand why copying unnecessary field names to output and then deleting them in the next step (Select step) is faster than not passing them at all?

Comment: if “omit said column” means that neither the field name nor its value will be output by the UDJC step, then this is suitable for me, but I do not understand how I can do this.

Comment: By omiting i mean that you don't need to get rid of the column during the transformation for it to output, say you begin with 3 Columns, A B C, and you end up with 6, you don't necessarily need to erase 1 or 2, you can just select which ones are to be outputed.

Comment: In my example, the output will have the same 3 fields as the input, just with different values. I am trying to figure out HOW to select which ones are to be outputed.

Comment: If a step needs to add or remove fields in the row array, use the static helper methods of RowDataUtil. (see documentation https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.0/0R0/0V0/010/000/020/010 )

Comment: As you can see in my code, I already use this method, but if I reduce the size of the output array, I will output fields with the names A and B. I also need them to have other names (A and C or D and E). In the future, I may need them to have other data types. I don't understand how to change the names and types of output fields.
I can add output fields with names D and E and other types, but they will go after fields A, B, and C (or I don't understand something).

Comment: I rephrase the question: is it possible to remove all input fields from output, and then add all those fields that are marked as output to there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that was required was:

1. save **data.outputRowMeta** in a variable of type RowMetaInterface (in my case **rowMeta**);
2. call the **rowMeta.removeValueMeta** method for it with the name or index of the field to delete;
3. search for indexes of output fields and the amount of output data using **rowMeta** instead of **getInputRowMeta()**;
4. in the **putRow()** method, use **rowMeta** as the first parameter.

``

```
private String outFieldName1;
private String outFieldName2;
private String removeFieldName;

private int outFieldIndex1;
private int outFieldIndex2;

private Object[] inputRow;

private int inputRowMetaSize;
private int outputRowMetaSize;
private RowMetaInterface rowMeta;

public boolean processRow(StepMetaInterface smi, StepDataInterface sdi) throws KettleException
{
    inputRow = getRow();
    if (inputRow == null) {
        setOutputDone();
        return false;
    }

    if (first) processMetadata();

    pushOutputRow( get(Fields.In, removeFieldName).getString(inputRow) + " "
                 + get(Fields.In, outFieldName2).getString(inputRow));

    return true;
}

private void processMetadata() throws KettleException {
    outFieldName1 = getParameter("OUT1");
    outFieldName2 = getParameter("OUT2");
    removeFieldName = getParameter("REMOVE");

    inputRowMetaSize = data.inputRowMeta.size();
    outputRowMetaSize = data.outputRowMeta.size();

    rowMeta = data.outputRowMeta;
    rowMeta.removeValueMeta(removeFieldName);

    outFieldIndex1 = rowMeta.indexOfValue(outFieldName1);
    outFieldIndex2 = rowMeta.indexOfValue(outFieldName2);

    outputRowMetaSize = rowMeta.size();

    first=false;
}

private void pushOutputRow(String content) throws KettleException {
    Object[] outRow = RowDataUtil.allocateRowData(outputRowMetaSize);

    for (int fieldN=0; fieldN < inputRow.length; ++fieldN) {

        if(fieldN == outFieldIndex1) {
            outRow[fieldN] = inputRow[fieldN];
        } else if(fieldN == outFieldIndex2) {
            outRow[fieldN] = content;
        }
    }

    putRow( rowMeta, outRow );
}
```

``